# Is there a tag for those create exhaustive lists of opportunities?

Tags: abnormal-psychology

When someone is incapable of making a choice **on behalf of others**, and structures everything they do to present every possible option and opportunity, what tends to be the cause of this?

Comment: Possibilities: 1) a rigid personality that tends to have to consider all possibilities, 2) no emotional drive to choose one thing over another, 3) fear of choosing wrongly. I have no research for this, but that is what comes to mind. Sometimes it is called "analysis paralysis" and there has been a lot written about that. Please add more details about the situation you describe by: "*structures everything they do to present every possible option and opportunity*"? Do you mean making opportunities for others, or trying to consider everything before deciding?

Comment: Read the first part of the sentence more strongly, as though it's in bold. That should answer both your questions.